# PropertyChangedTrigger in WP8 not working

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I need to create a percent loader control. I created a two Arc control. One Arc is for background and one for foreground. I will giving the end angle as a input to the Arc. I wrote a double animation class to perform loading animation. When i tried to invoke the story board in the code behind, animation works.

But my requirement is, whenever a property changes, I need to load the loader. So i decided to use PropertyChangedBehaviour. But animation is not working. Please suggest the best way to do this'

Here is xaml code:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValueStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="On">
                <Storyboard x:Name="storyBoard2">
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:9" To="270" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Arc.EndAngle)" Storyboard.TargetName="TimerProgressBar">
                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    </DoubleAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1"
                  Background="Transparent"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Margin="0 40 0 0">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <ec:PropertyChangedTrigger Binding="{Binding EndAngleValue}">
                        <ec:GoToStateAction StateName="On"/>
                    </ec:PropertyChangedTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <es:Arc ArcThickness="1"
                        Fill="{StaticResource OlaTextLightGrayBrush}"
                        ArcThicknessUnit="Pixel"
                        Stretch="None"
                        Stroke="{StaticResource OlaTextLightGrayBrush}"
                        StartAngle="0"
                        EndAngle="360"
                        UseLayoutRounding="False"
                        Width="297"
                        Height="297" />

                <es:Arc ArcThickness="4"
                        Fill="{StaticResource OlaGreenBrush}"
                        x:Name="TimerProgressBar"
                        ArcThicknessUnit="Pixel"
                        Stretch="None"
                        StartAngle="0"
                        UseLayoutRounding="False"
                        Width="300"
                        Height="300" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" >

                    <es:Arc.Stroke>
                        <SolidColorBrush 
                            Color="{StaticResource OlaGreen}"/>
                    </es:Arc.Stroke>
                </es:Arc>
```

My View Model:

```
public double EndAngleValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _EndAngleValue;
        }

        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _EndAngleValue, value);
        }
    }
```

Whenever the property 'EndAngleValue' changes, i need to perform animation.

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Have you implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` in view model?

Comment: Is your `VisualStateManager` defined in the root of the control?

Comment: Yes Visual state manager is defined in the root.

Comment: Yes INotifyPropertyChanged has been inherited.

Answer (score 0):

If you've implemented then you should be able to do this:

```
public double EndAngleValue
{
    get
    {
        return _EndAngleValue;
    }

    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _EndAngleValue, value);
        OnPropertyChanged("EndAngleValue");
    }
}

private OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if(PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```